# Detecting and Removing Noise from Signal using Python

Tags: signal-analysis, python, noise, frequency-domain, noise-cancellation

Through this platform, I want to ask that how can I remove unwanted noise from the signal when you do not have much information regarding the frequency at which they appear? Data is collected from an inductive sensor and sampling frequency is 30000 Hz. There are a lot of electrical noises in the signal, the easily distinguishible have already been removed using a Notch Filter. However, there are some electrical noises which are not easily distinguishible from the other parts of the signal. I tested the following approaches:

- Removing easily visible electrical noises using Notch Filter
- Taking FFT and applying binning to visualize other noisy parts
- Using find_peaks() function to detect and remove noisy parts

However, when I appled ifft I could not get the filtered original time series data.

This is the Original Time Series Signal:

[image: Original Time Series Signal]

This is the complex Fourier Transform before binning and find_peaks():

[image]

And this is the fourier transform after binning:

[image]

And this is the result obtained after find_peaks():

[image]

And this is the inverse FFT result that I have obtained after so called processing (FFT, binnig, find_peaks() technique)

[image]

Can anyone please help me understand where I went wrong?

This is the reference data obtained usinf Eddy Current Sensor. I suppose my data should also look likr this after denoising.

[image]

Comment: Hi Aisha, welcome to SP.SE! We're going to need a lot more information here. What are the characteristics of your signal? Give as much detail as possible (**what kind of sensor**: microphone, accelerometer, etc; **type of data**: audio, seismic, etc; **sampling rate**; **frequency spread**: narrow-band, broadband, etc). What are the characteristics of your noise? You need to share as much info as you can, and time / frequency plots to see what we're dealing with here.

Comment: Sure, lemme edit my post.

Comment: Filtering depends on knowing what you want to keep and what you want to reject (think of a coffee filter -- little stuff, like molecules, is tasty and desirable; big stuff is gritty and bitter).  Can you describe what you expect your _desired_ signal to be?  As a start, filtering to only pass the desired stuff and filter out all the rest may work.

Comment: While we're at it, you say it's an inductive sensor -- what are you sensing with it?  Are you sensing something like magnetic fields (in which case you want what comes out of the sensor as-is), or is it a proximity sensor or an LVDT, in which case the information you want is riding on some sort of modulated signal.

Comment: Yes, this is an inductive sensor and it is creating signals on the basis of the magnetic fields generated. And honestly, I don’t know how exactly the signal should look. I just observed some electrical spikes and tried to remove them.

Comment: The data has been obtained from the inductive sensor attached under the train. Now, when the train moves on the rail the sensor generates the data.

Comment: Just to clarify: are we talking about an actual train?  If so, what does "heart" mean in this context? A high pass filter could much improve the signal quality, as the train would be bound to have a maximum velocity. Or is this about vibration? What do you actually want to measure/see? Also the signal looks clipped to me.

Comment: So, for this project I am required to classify rail switch. Heart is basically the point where two rail tracks are crossing over and depending on the switch direction the train moves on one of the tracks. Yes, I am talking about the actual train. However, this signal is just a reference. Actually my data contains a lot of transitions and I cannot say anything sure about the baseline shape of my signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The train moves at speed $v_t$. This (absolute) speed reasonably will have a supremum $v_{t\max}$. It obviously has an infimum of $0$, but there is nothing to measure with a train standing around. So we declare some minimum speed we are interested in and call that $v_{t\min}$.

The rail fasteners are spaced at a distance of $d$, which can be assumed as constant for these purposes. The transitions at the "heart" points can with some reason be assumed to be in the same order of magnitude as $d$.

From this, we can derive the part of the spectrum we are interested in. For the lower corner frequency, we take $v_{t\min}$ and add some margin, say, a decade, below. That gives us
$$f_l = 0.1\frac{v_{t\min}}{d}$$
We do the same for the upper corner frequency and set the margin again to a decade, above this time of course:
$$f_u = 10\frac{v_{t\max}}{d}$$
With these two corner frequencies, design a bandpass to filter the signal. You should be able to see a lot more than before. From there further steps can be taken.

Remark on your attempts so far:
The operations you performed on the spectrum where *nonlinear*, so the inverse FFT was bound to produce rubbish.

Comment: The distance between the rail fastners can be known. But what if I do not have information regarding the speed of train owing to the data provided? Secondly, you are saying that my approach on filtering was incorrect?

Comment: If the speed of the train is unknown, make some reasonable assumptions. It most probably won't go faster than 200mph. Secondly, I did not say it was incorrect. It was just nonlinear (at least the find_peaks function). That makes transforming the signal back into the time domain pointless.

Comment: The approach that you have mentioned is certainly interesting. However, I am thinking to go for a lazy approach: I will apply notch filters on each frequency till 100 Hz (becase either ways we are going to ignore samples greater than 100 Hz). I am going for this lazy approach because I have a deadline to follow for the submission of my Thesis

Comment: I have also tried using 'noisereduce' tool of python as mentioned in this link: https://pypi.org/project/noisereduce/#:~:text=Noisereduce%20is%20a%20noise%20reduction%20algorithm%20in%20python,gating%22%20which%20is%20a%20form%20of%20Noise%20Gate. Can this be helpful?

Comment: Just to clarify more: what exactly do you want to do? Above, you said you want to "classify rail switch". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Definitely. So my main task is to classify rail switch using Machine Learning. For that, I need to do some signal processing to remove noise from the data otherwise it can effect the accuracy of my model. Note that: I need to remove electrical noises in time domain and then go to position domain (plot the sensor data against position), remove some wheel spinning effects dependent on position and then do feature engineering and machine learning in Position Domain. Time Domain signal processing is just to remove electrical noises and spikes.

Comment: I have used noisereduce tool of python (as mentioned in the link posted above) and it has actually removed spikes from the signal. But I am not sure whether it is a correct approach to adopt or not

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So what I would do is: first apply a low pass filter with corner frequency 100+x Hz, then remove the DC components with a highpass filter with corner frequency around 1Hz or something. Then try the noisereduce package on the thus filtered signal.

Comment: I am getting your point. But why are you applying the low pass and high pass filters if the noisereduce package is fulfilling the purpose? and did you assume those cut-off frequencies? I would like to show you my signal after applying noisereduce package but I think here I cannot do that

Comment: I have not used the package, but my thinking is that generally it will produce better results the cleaner the input signal is. The 100Hz comes from your comment, 1Hz is just shot from the hip.

Comment: Oh yes yes. I will definitely try the approach you have mentioned in your answer above but maybe after creating the Machine Learning model so that I do not have much to worry about